# Creating a dataframe column with each cell having the sum of all values with a certain trait

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two pandas' DataFrames, say:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Type": [A, A, B, B, C], "data": [1,2,3,4,5]}) 

        Type  data
    0     A     1
    1     A     2
    2     B     3
    3     B     4
    4     C     5
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Type": [A, B, C]}) 

        Type 
    0     A 
    1     B
    2     C
```

and I want to adjoint a column to `df2`, say "Value", such that each cell in Value has the sum of all elements in `df1["Col2"]` that belong to the same Type.

The desired output, for this particular example, would look lie this:

```
        Type  data
    0     A     3
    1     B     7
    2     C     5
```

I feel tempted to use a `while` for each `x` in `df2["Type"]` and just add all `df1[df1["Type"] == x]["data"]` but this doesn't seem like propper form.

How could I achieve this desired output?

Comment: Check groupby sum

Comment: You can try `df2 = df1.groupby(['Type']).sum()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method will depend on what is in df1 and df2.

**All Types are in Both DataFrames:**

Assuming types A, B, and C are the only types available, you can use a simple [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) function to receive the sum for each type.

```
df1.groupby(by='Type',as_index=False).sum()
```

```
  Type  data
0    A     3
1    B     7
2    C     5
```

**Both DataFrames Contain Different Types:**

If df1 has types that df2 does not have (or vice versa), then it would be appropriate to [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) the two dataframes and then use the groupby function for the merged dataframes.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'Type':['A','A','B','B','C'], 'data':[1,2,3,4,5]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'Type':['A','A','B','D','E']})

df_merged = df1.merge(df2,on='Type',how='outer')
df_merged.groupby(by='Type',as_index=False).sum()
```

```
  Type  data
0    A   6.0
1    B   7.0
2    C   5.0
3    D   0.0
4    E   0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Via merging and grouping by `Type` column:

```
df1.merge(df2, on='Type').groupby('Type').sum().reset_index()
```

---

```
  Type  data
0    A     3
1    B     7
2    C     5
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Type": ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C'], "data": [1,2,3,4,5]}) 
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Type": ['A', 'B', 'C']}) 

df1['cumsum'] = df1.groupby('Type').agg({'data':'cumsum'})
df2['data'] = (df1.drop_duplicates(subset=['Type'], keep='last'))['cumsum'].reset_index(drop=True)

print(df2)
```

```
  Type  data
0    A     3
1    B     7
2    C     5
```